# XSS on marketing websites like craigslist. How does this work on a technical level?

Tags: xss, server, phishing

I was wondering how this works.
We have a marketing site in Holland where people can sell second hand goods.
Rumor goes that there is a lot of phishing going on there and XSS code is used in the images that are uploaded to the site for malicious intent.

Can someone explain to me how this works and how people can stay out of trouble?
I have some theoretical understanding of protocols and scripting.
Examples or 3rd party source for clarification are most appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly (do you know how XSS works already?) but all I can say is that if threre's stored XSS it might not be possible for users to avoid it (the website itself is infected). But if it's just reflected XSS, it can be mitigated by avoiding to click on any suspicious links and by always logging out of the website as soon as you're done.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but what you are saying is that if the " hosting server " is nfected, than so is the complete site with all on it. If not; only the uploaded content is infected such as a image or redirecting link or other form of media content. Am I right? I am trying to get my head around it all. The whole concept of cros site scripting, server, site. How does it work? And how could I reproduce it in lab environment to play with it myself, just for education. Are you willing to help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking about how XSS works or are you asking how users can avoid XSS stored in images on sites? Your post says one thing, but your comment says another.

Comment: I was just pointing out the distinction between stored and reflected XSS. It was not clear from the question what you knew about XSS already. If you are not familiar with the basic concepts of XSS and how websites are coded in general, then you need to look them up (on Google, or here on Stack Exchange, etc.). Otherwise your questions might not be clear or be too broad.